# Need for additional Master Port Role in MSTP

Tags: spanning-tree, bridge, ieee-802.1w, ieee-802.1s

MSTP IEEE specification, it says the Root Port for CIST will be the Master Port for all MSTIs. I'm wondering what is the need for this additional port role, is it just to isolate the region boundaries since all vlans must go through this link ? and also the role of disputed flag in used for Master Port role transitions